# How to have Kendo observable.get return only object data?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

When kendo observable.get returns an object, it adds other properties such as uid and _events.

For example,

```
var observable = new kendo.data.ObservableObject();
var myCar = {make: "toyota", model: "camry"};
observable.set("car", myCar);
var carVar = observable.get("car");
console.log(carVar);
```

The console logs:

[image]

Working example is located [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/EmOgIMIW)

How can I get the original object without the added properties?

Answer (score 0):

Try toJSON()

```
console.log(carVar.toJSON());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const observable = new kendo.data.ObservableObject();
const myCar = {make: "toyota", model: "camry"};
observable.set("car", myCar);
const carVar = observable.get("car");
```

You can either make a list of the relevant keys or get them from the original object like this:

```
const keys = ["make", "model"];
// or
const keys = Object.keys(myCar);
```

Here's the code to get an object containing only entries for the original keys from the new object:

```
keys.reduce((prev, current) => ({
    ...prev,
    [current]: extra[current]
}), {})
```